# Adversarial attacks on non image data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, research

Reading the literature around deep learning adversarial attacks it appears to be wholly concentrated on attacks of image classification models. Are there papers that describe attacks on non image data ? Searching archive for deep learning adversarial attacks appears to contain results that are just related to image classification field.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for ai.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

[Carlini and Wagner (2018), “Audio Adversarial Examples: Targeted Attacks on Speech-to-Text”](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01944.pdf)